# Replacing a ceiling light fixture, I found a wire adapter

Tags: electrical, wiring

The existing pendant light is Ikea, which I removed. The wires were plugged into some kind of an adapter, as shown in the attached pictures. I am not sure if this is something new that they include with their products.

The new pendant light is a standard one, with three wires (black, white, ground). My house has copper wiring.

I am attaching pictures of the adapter. I even wouldn't mind using it, if only I knew anything about how to use it properly. My google search didn't produce much. The side of the adapter says CB-HFT tube, but that only indicates the shrink-wrapped tube.

Should I just remove this adapter, or is there a male part of the adapter that I should find for the new light pendant? Also, can anyone give more info on this adapter?
[image][image][image]

Comment: From the wire colors, you're in North America, right?

Comment: Yes, North America.

Answer (score 2):

I would cut the existing ends off and use wire nuts to make the connection. Just about every hardware store will have wire nuts and even some grocery store’s have small bags. Cut the wires off strip the insulation and twist the nut on and it is done in seconds. 
Added

I have not seen adapters for these styles of plugs usually you have to find the right style , cut the wrong one off crimp the ends then insert them into the new shell , so you can see wire nuts would be much easier and quicker.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will try that and give an update.

Comment: A course if they pull out the adapter completely they'll probably find that it, itself is wire nutted and then could just go off it for the new.